# Binding to ImageView.Drawable with MvvmCross Xamarin.Android App

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'd like to display circular images in my Xamarin.Android app. [This blog post](http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tricks-vignette-image-effect/), looks like it'll give me what I want. But I'd like to use MvvmCross to data bind.

Before I begin, is it the correct approach to create a value converter that would take an image path (or some other reference to an image) and return my circular drawable, then bind that to the Drawable property of [ImageView](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.Widget.ImageView.Drawable)

Comment: Hello, looking at doing the same thing! Do you get this working? could you share the convert please? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really think there will be just one "the correct approach", but the approach you've suggested looks plausible to me.

If it helps, MvvmCross provides a "Bitmap" pseudo-property on `ImageView` to allow you to bind to a `Bitmap` - eg from a value converter. Beyond this, you could also implement your own custom binding if you wanted to (the built-in bitmap binding targets are in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target and are fairly easy to reuse)